# Unable to SSH into any cloud VM Instance like GCP, AWS, Digital Ocean and even unable to clone github repository using SSH

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh, google-cloud-platform, digital-ocean

I have two laptops, one running fedora and another running mint. Both gets connected using ssh when are on same network.

Recently I started cloud computing, but unfortunately I am unable to ssh into cloud VM's from none of my laptop.
I have tried many service providers like GCP, AWS and Digital Ocean.

Yes, I have read their respective documentation, followed them but every time when I try to ssh into them, the terminal goes Connection Timed Out.
Both my laptop return Connection Timed Out.

But when I connect using browser based terminal, a new browser window appears and have terminal but it's extremely slow.

One more thing: recently I tried to clone a GitHub repository using SSH.
But same error again: Connection Timed Out.

Can anyone help me out for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If this is really systematic, meaning:

- if SSH works for LAN servers (on the same local network)
- but SSH does not work for WAN remote servers (outside your local network)

that looks like a [network/firewall restriction](https://superuser.com/a/643828/141), which prevents any SSH communication.